# Info in cmd blinks and updates very fast

Tags: c++

I've just written my first snake game at c++ (congratz me). But there's one problem - the cmd updates very fast that's why snake moves really fast, it's just impossible to play and eat fruits

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for). Something like:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

Comment: This will jitter with CPU load. Waiting for a given time after last update would result in a constant period. Admittedly, the jitter might be unnoticable in a program as simple as this seems to be, judging from OPs description as "really fast".

Comment: Indeed, but he/she will learn more advanced topics needed for real-time graphics later on :)